# No write permission for user to mounted filesystem in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, mount

I've mounted a filesystem from an external drive. The problem is that users has no write permissions to that mounted volume, but root has. Filesystem type is `exFAT`.
The volume is owned by root. Output of `ls -l` command:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 131072 Aug 27 15:04 dir
```

I tried to change the owner of the directory using this command `chown -R user /mnt`.
But I get this error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt': Operation not permitted
```

even though I ran this command from root.

Command `chmod -R 777 /mnt` just outputs nothing and do nothing. It doesn't change the permissions.
Then I tried to figure out why the command `chown` outputs that operation not permitted and I found on the Internet that the directory might be immutable, so I should've remove the immutable flag using this command `chattr -i /mnt`. But this command didn't work either. It's just output this:

```
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /mnt
```

Of cource I ran this command from root.
So, why I can't change and give write permissions for user to this volume?
Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

`mount` output:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type exfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: Not knowing what mount program you are using, but the fuse-exfat says you can give umask, dmask & fmask options to allow other users to faullt access files. `man mount.fuse-exfat` for details.

Comment: Well the filesystem (or at least the driver implementation) does not support it. TL;DR, use e.g `uid=` and `gid=` mount options, or even better, use `udisksctl` to mount it with a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

I use Arch Linux and I had no `exfat-utils` package installed. I needed to install this package to get mount work correctly.